# Confirm deletion in modal / dialog using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML table of rows tied to database rows. I'd like to have a "delete row" link for each row, but I would like to confirm with the user beforehand.

Is there any way to do this using the Twitter Bootstrap modal dialog?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MjmVr/363/

Comment: Having run across this question I wanted to chime-in with (what seems to me) such a simple and more streamlined "fix" for this issue. I struggled with it for a while and then realized how simple it can be: just put the actual form submission button in the modal dialog, and then the submit button on the form itself does nothing but fire the dialog window... problem solved.

Comment: @jonijones this example is not working for me (the confirmation message doesn't display upon click of the first button) - tested in chrome

Answer (score 428, accepted):

### GET recipe

For this task you can use already available plugins and bootstrap extensions. Or you can make your own confirmation popup with just **3** lines of code. Check it out.

Say we have this links (note `data-href` instead of `href`) or buttons that we want to have delete confirmation for:

```
<a href="#" data-href="delete.php?id=23" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">Delete record #23</a>

<button class="btn btn-default" data-href="/delete.php?id=54" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
    Delete record #54
</button>
```

Here `#confirm-delete` points to a modal popup div in your HTML. It should have an "OK" button configured like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you only need this little javascript to make a delete action confirmable:

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

So on `show.bs.modal` event delete button `href` is set to URL with corresponding record id.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NePR0BQf3VmKtuMmhVR7?p=preview

---

### POST recipe

I realize that in some cases there might be needed to perform POST or DELETE request rather then GET. It it still pretty simple without too much code. Take a look at the demo below with this approach:

```
// Bind click to OK button within popup
$('#confirm-delete').on('click', '.btn-ok', function(e) {

  var $modalDiv = $(e.delegateTarget);
  var id = $(this).data('recordId');

  $modalDiv.addClass('loading');
  $.post('/api/record/' + id).then(function() {
     $modalDiv.modal('hide').removeClass('loading');
  });
});

// Bind to modal opening to set necessary data properties to be used to make request
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var data = $(e.relatedTarget).data();
  $('.title', this).text(data.recordTitle);
  $('.btn-ok', this).data('recordId', data.recordId);
});
```

```js
// Bind click to OK button within popup
$('#confirm-delete').on('click', '.btn-ok', function(e) {

  var $modalDiv = $(e.delegateTarget);
  var id = $(this).data('recordId');

  $modalDiv.addClass('loading');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $modalDiv.modal('hide').removeClass('loading');
  }, 1000);

  // In reality would be something like this
  // $modalDiv.addClass('loading');
  // $.post('/api/record/' + id).then(function() {
  //   $modalDiv.modal('hide').removeClass('loading');
  // });
});

// Bind to modal opening to set necessary data properties to be used to make request
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var data = $(e.relatedTarget).data();
  $('.title', this).text(data.recordTitle);
  $('.btn-ok', this).data('recordId', data.recordId);
});
```

```css
.modal.loading .modal-content:before {
  content: 'Loading...';
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 155px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #EEE;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are about to delete <b><i class="title"></i></b> record, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
        <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" data-record-id="23" data-record-title="The first one" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
        Delete "The first one", #23
    </a>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-default" data-record-id="54" data-record-title="Something cool" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
  Delete "Something cool", #54
</button>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/V4GUuSueuuxiGr4L9LmG?p=preview

---

### Bootstrap 2.3

Here is an original version of the code I made when I was answering this question for Bootstrap 2.3 modal.

```
$('#modal').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');
    removeBtn.attr('href', removeBtn.attr('href').replace(/(&|\?)ref=\d*/, '$1ref=' + id));
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/MjmVr/1595/

Comment: This works almost perfectly but even in the fiddle version (as in my site), the id isn't passed to the Yes button in the modal.  I did notice that you're trying to replace **&ref** instead of **?ref** so I tried changing that but it still isn't working.  Am I missing something else here?  This is otherwise great so TIA for your help!

Comment: Thanks @dfsq - this worked beautifully.  The dialog isn't hiding on clicking the 'no' button so I changed the href to # rather than the modal hide and that works as well.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I had the same with the &ref/?ref and fixed it. But also I have a problem, that the modal window shows up right after my entire page is loaded. When I put javascript code after the HTML modal, bind doesn't work (and id rewrite fails). When I do it the other way round or surround JS code with `$(window).load(function(){ ... });`, the modal shows up during initial page rendering. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: One tweak is the final delete request should result in a post, not a GEt as you would with a link.  If you allow Delete's on a GET, then malicious third parties can easily craft links on sites or emails that cause your user's to unwittingly delete things.  It might seem silly, but there are scenarios where this would be a serious security problem.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome). So much simpler to do what you're asking: http://jsfiddle.net/adamschwartz/hQump.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but the provided the solution (nor the plnkr link) is working for me. The moment I click on one of the links I can see a request is sent to http://run.plnkr.co/delete.php?id=xx which should not happen before the dialog is confirmed

Comment: @DanielFreudenberger You mean this demo doesn't work for you http://plnkr.co/edit/UaDNofbtHXGdcG4UzyAR?p=preview ? Check console, maybe you have javascript disabled or some specific scripts are blocked for you? It works fine for me.

Comment: @dsfq just open your browsers network tab (developer toolbar) and take a look what happens when you click on one of the links. Of course the dialog opens but at the same moment bootstrap will try to load the "remote content" from the provided href value

Comment: @DanielFreudenberger Thank you for finding a problem. I indeed recently updated the answer and didn't notice a new bug. Now I reverted to original code and also added `button` example.

Comment: Can I make a POST with this method?

Comment: @olefrank Yes, of course. Just instead of `$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));` bind click event to the ok button which would send POST. I guess I need to update post with this recipe. Someone already raised concern.

Comment: @dfsq: Cool! But how do I specify a button to use method POST? As far as I know it can only use GET...

Comment: Tempted to downvote for using a GET to perform a destructive action.
There are many, many different reasons you should never do that.

Comment: @NickG That's why there is a POST recipe. Anyway original question was about some admin panel table anyway, so no big deal in having GET links there ;)

Comment: How is "loading" class working in your POST recipe? I do not see any `loading` defined anywhere.

Comment: Coming to this answer years later to say that in Bootstrap 5 at least, the data attributes now have "-bs" in them, i.e. data-bs-toggle, data-bs-target, data-bs-dismiss, etc.

Answer (score 165):

http://bootboxjs.com/ - latest works with Bootstrap 3.0.0

The simplest possible example:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!");
```

From the site:

> The library exposes three methods designed to mimic their native JavaScript equivalents. Their exact method signatures are flexible as each can take various parameters to customise labels and specify defaults, but they are most commonly called like so:

```
bootbox.alert(message, callback)
bootbox.prompt(message, callback)
bootbox.confirm(message, callback)
```

Here's a snippet of it in action (click "Run code snippet" below):

```js
$(function() {
  bootbox.alert("Hello world!");
});
```

```html
<!-- required includes -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- bootbox.js at 4.4.0 -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/f3a04a57877cab071738de558581fbc91812dce9/bootbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the moment you need non-english text on title and buttons you either have to modify the JS or start parameterizing almost as much as just adding the bootstrap html and JS yourself. :)

Answer (score 31):

```
  // ---------------------------------------------------------- Generic Confirm  

  function confirm(heading, question, cancelButtonTxt, okButtonTxt, callback) {

    var confirmModal = 
      $('<div class="modal hide fade">' +    
          '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</a>' +
            '<h3>' + heading +'</h3>' +
          '</div>' +

          '<div class="modal-body">' +
            '<p>' + question + '</p>' +
          '</div>' +

          '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">' + 
              cancelButtonTxt + 
            '</a>' +
            '<a href="#" id="okButton" class="btn btn-primary">' + 
              okButtonTxt + 
            '</a>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>');

    confirmModal.find('#okButton').click(function(event) {
      callback();
      confirmModal.modal('hide');
    });

    confirmModal.modal('show');     
  };

  // ---------------------------------------------------------- Confirm Put To Use

  $("i#deleteTransaction").live("click", function(event) {
    // get txn id from current table row
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    var heading = 'Confirm Transaction Delete';
    var question = 'Please confirm that you wish to delete transaction ' + id + '.';
    var cancelButtonTxt = 'Cancel';
    var okButtonTxt = 'Confirm';

    var callback = function() {
      alert('delete confirmed ' + id);
    };

    confirm(heading, question, cancelButtonTxt, okButtonTxt, callback);

  });
```

Comment: Its a old post but i want the same thing to do but when i use the above code the modal dialog dosent show ?

Answer (score 30):

I'd realise its a very old question, but since i wondered today for a more efficient method of handling the bootstrap modals. I did some research and found something better then the solutions which are shown above, that can be found at this link:

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/809.cfm

First load the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then just ask any question/confirmation to href:

```
<a href="/any/url/delete.php?ref=ID" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?">Delete</a>
```

This way the confirmation modal is a lot more universal and so it can easily be re-used on other parts of your website.

Comment: Please do not post code from other sources without attribution: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/809.cfm.

Comment: Even though the op forgot the attribution at first, this was the perfect thing for me. Works like a charm.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea delete items with a GET http request

Comment: GET or POST, the most important thing is that you check server-side to ensure that the user performing the action actually has the permission level necessary to delete items.  POST can be spoofed just as easily as GET.

Comment: Momma told me not to click any cold fusion links

Comment: @BenY It's not about whether the user has permission to do things or not, it's about malicious users that already *have permission* to do things being tricked into clicking links on other sites, emails etc so the malicious user can take advantage of that users permissions.

Comment: In phpstorm is giving this error in `#dataConfirmModal` **Duplicated jQuery selector**

Comment: Tiago, then you have two modals or two times #dataConfirmModal as an id.. You probably als can do it with a class. Then it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to @Jousby's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124151/522150), I managed to get mine working as well, but found I had to improve his solution's Bootstrap modal markup a bit to make it render correctly as demonstrated in the official [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples).

So, here's my modified version of the generic `confirm` function that worked fine:

```
/* Generic Confirm func */
  function confirm(heading, question, cancelButtonTxt, okButtonTxt, callback) {

    var confirmModal = 
      $('<div class="modal fade">' +        
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
          '<div class="modal-content">' +
          '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</a>' +
            '<h3>' + heading +'</h3>' +
          '</div>' +

          '<div class="modal-body">' +
            '<p>' + question + '</p>' +
          '</div>' +

          '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<a href="#!" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">' + 
              cancelButtonTxt + 
            '</a>' +
            '<a href="#!" id="okButton" class="btn btn-primary">' + 
              okButtonTxt + 
            '</a>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>');

    confirmModal.find('#okButton').click(function(event) {
      callback();
      confirmModal.modal('hide');
    }); 

    confirmModal.modal('show');    
  };  
/* END Generic Confirm func */
```

Comment: Great solution here. I made some slight modifications to handle a callback for the cancel link. One small recommendation use #! instead of # in your href to prevent the page from scrolling to the top.

Comment: If I could double up-vote this I would. Nice and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice solution. One more improvement I can suggest is to add another argument: `btnType = "btn-primary"` and then change the code for the OK button to contain `class="btn ' + btnType + '"`. That way one can pass an optional argument to change the appearance of the OK button, like `btn-danger` for a delete.

Comment: Thank you. I had to swap around the <h3> and <a> tags (h3 first) for this to render correctly.

Answer (score 10):

I found this useful and easy to use, plus it looks pretty: http://maxailloud.github.io/confirm-bootstrap/.

To use it, include the .js file in your page then run:

```
$('your-link-selector').confirmModal();
```

There are various options you can apply to it, to make it look better when doing it to confirm a delete, I use:

```
$('your-link-selector').confirmModal({
    confirmTitle: 'Please confirm',
    confirmMessage: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?',
    confirmStyle: 'danger',
    confirmOk: '<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete',
    confirmCallback: function (target) {
         //perform the deletion here, or leave this option
         //out to just follow link..
    }
});
```

Comment: that's a nice lib

Answer (score 4):

I can easily handle this type of task using bootbox.js library. At first you need to include bootbox JS file. Then in your event handler function simply write following code:

```
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure to want to delete , function(result) {

    //here result will be true
    // delete process code goes here

    });
```

Offical bootboxjs [site](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**Following solution is better than bootbox.js**, because

- It can do everything bootbox.js can do;
- The use syntax is simpler
- It allows you to elegantly control the color of your message using "error", "warning" or "info"
- Bootbox is 986 lines long, mine only 110 lines long

**digimango.messagebox.js**:

```js
const dialogTemplate = '\
    <div class ="modal" id="digimango_messageBox" role="dialog">\
        <div class ="modal-dialog">\
            <div class ="modal-content">\
                <div class ="modal-body">\
                    <p class ="text-success" id="digimango_messageBoxMessage">Some text in the modal.</p>\
                    <p><textarea id="digimango_messageBoxTextArea" cols="70" rows="5"></textarea></p>\
                </div>\
                <div class ="modal-footer">\
                    <button type="button" class ="btn btn-primary" id="digimango_messageBoxOkButton">OK</button>\
                    <button type="button" class ="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="digimango_messageBoxCancelButton">Cancel</button>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>';


// See the comment inside function digimango_onOkClick(event) {
var digimango_numOfDialogsOpened = 0;


function messageBox(msg, significance, options, actionConfirmedCallback) {
    if ($('#digimango_MessageBoxContainer').length == 0) {
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'digimango_MessageBoxContainer';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        $("#digimango_MessageBoxContainer").html(dialogTemplate);
    }

    var okButtonName, cancelButtonName, showTextBox, textBoxDefaultText;

    if (options == null) {
        okButtonName = 'OK';
        cancelButtonName = null;
        showTextBox = null;
        textBoxDefaultText = null;
    } else {
        okButtonName = options.okButtonName;
        cancelButtonName = options.cancelButtonName;
        showTextBox = options.showTextBox;
        textBoxDefaultText = options.textBoxDefaultText;
    }

    if (showTextBox == true) {
        if (textBoxDefaultText == null)
            $('#digimango_messageBoxTextArea').val('');
        else
            $('#digimango_messageBoxTextArea').val(textBoxDefaultText);

        $('#digimango_messageBoxTextArea').show();
    }
    else
        $('#digimango_messageBoxTextArea').hide();

    if (okButtonName != null)
        $('#digimango_messageBoxOkButton').html(okButtonName);
    else
        $('#digimango_messageBoxOkButton').html('OK');

    if (cancelButtonName == null)
        $('#digimango_messageBoxCancelButton').hide();
    else {
        $('#digimango_messageBoxCancelButton').show();
        $('#digimango_messageBoxCancelButton').html(cancelButtonName);
    }

    $('#digimango_messageBoxOkButton').unbind('click');
    $('#digimango_messageBoxOkButton').on('click', { callback: actionConfirmedCallback }, digimango_onOkClick);

    $('#digimango_messageBoxCancelButton').unbind('click');
    $('#digimango_messageBoxCancelButton').on('click', digimango_onCancelClick);

    var content = $("#digimango_messageBoxMessage");

    if (significance == 'error')
        content.attr('class', 'text-danger');
    else if (significance == 'warning')
        content.attr('class', 'text-warning');
    else
        content.attr('class', 'text-success');

    content.html(msg);

    if (digimango_numOfDialogsOpened == 0)
        $("#digimango_messageBox").modal();

    digimango_numOfDialogsOpened++;
}

function digimango_onOkClick(event) {
    // JavaScript's nature is unblocking. So the function call in the following line will not block,
    // thus the last line of this function, which is to hide the dialog, is executed before user
    // clicks the "OK" button on the second dialog shown in the callback. Therefore we need to count
    // how many dialogs is currently showing. If we know there is still a dialog being shown, we do
    // not execute the last line in this function.
    if (typeof (event.data.callback) != 'undefined')
        event.data.callback($('#digimango_messageBoxTextArea').val());

    digimango_numOfDialogsOpened--;

    if (digimango_numOfDialogsOpened == 0)
        $('#digimango_messageBox').modal('hide');
}

function digimango_onCancelClick() {
    digimango_numOfDialogsOpened--;

    if (digimango_numOfDialogsOpened == 0)
        $('#digimango_messageBox').modal('hide');
}
```

To use **digimango.messagebox.js**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>A useful generic message box</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/digimango.messagebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testAlert() {
            messageBox('Something went wrong!', 'error');
        }

        function testAlertWithCallback() {
            messageBox('Something went wrong!', 'error', null, function () {
                messageBox('OK clicked.');
            });
        }

        function testConfirm() {
            messageBox('Do you want to proceed?', 'warning', { okButtonName: 'Yes', cancelButtonName: 'No' }, function () {
                messageBox('Are you sure you want to proceed?', 'warning', { okButtonName: 'Yes', cancelButtonName: 'No' });
            });
        }

        function testPrompt() {
            messageBox('How do you feel now?', 'normal', { showTextBox: true }, function (userInput) {
                messageBox('User entered "' + userInput + '".');
            });
        }

        function testPromptWithDefault() {
            messageBox('How do you feel now?', 'normal', { showTextBox: true, textBoxDefaultText: 'I am good!' }, function (userInput) {
                messageBox('User entered "' + userInput + '".');
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="testAlert();">Test alert</a> <br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="testAlertWithCallback();">Test alert with callback</a> <br />
    <a href="#" onclick="testConfirm();">Test confirm</a> <br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="testPrompt();">Test prompt</a><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="testPromptWithDefault();">Test prompt with default text</a> <br />
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When its comes to a relevantly big project we may need something **re-usable**. This is something I came with with help of SO.

### confirmDelete.jsp

```
<!-- Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDelete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel"
 aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Parmanently</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 75px">
            <p>Are you sure about this ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm-delete-ok">Ok
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var url_for_deletion = "#";
    var success_redirect = window.location.href;

$('#confirmDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var message = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-message');
    $(this).find('.modal-body p').text(message);
    var title = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-title');
    $(this).find('.modal-title').text(title);

    if (typeof  $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-url') != 'undefined') {
        url_for_deletion = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-url');
    }
    if (typeof  $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-success-url') != 'undefined') {
        success_redirect = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-success-url');
    }

});

<!-- Form confirm (yes/ok) handler, submits form -->
$('#confirmDelete').find('.modal-footer #confirm-delete-ok').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "delete",
        url: url_for_deletion,
    }).success(function (data) {
        window.location.href = success_redirect;
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    $('#confirmDelete').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
<script/>
```

### reusingPage.jsp

```
<a href="#" class="table-link danger"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#confirmDelete"
data-title="Delete Something"
data-message="Are you sure you want to inactivate this something?"
data-url="client/32"
id="delete-client-32">
</a>
<!-- jQuery should come before this -->
<%@ include file="../some/path/confirmDelete.jsp" %>
```

**Note:** This uses http delete method for delete request, you can change it from javascript or, can send it using a data-attribute as in data-title or data-url etc, for support any request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in the easiest shortcut, then u can do it with [**this plugin**](http://bootboxjs.com/).

---

But this plugin is an alternate implementation using [Bootstrap Modal](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/). And real Bootstrap implementation is also very easy, so I don't like to use this plugin because it adds excess JS contents in the page, which will slow down the page loading time.

---

### Idea

I like to implement it by myself by this way-

1. If **user click**s on a button to delete an item from the list, then a JS call will put **Item ID** (or any more essential data) in a form in the modal.
2. Then in the pop-up, there will be 2 buttons for confirmation.

   - ***Yes*** will submit the form (with ajax or direct form submit)
   - ***No*** will just dismiss the modal

---

The code will be like this (using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/))-

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        //Say - $('p').get(0).id - this delete item id
        $("#delete_item_id").val( $('p').get(0).id );
        $('#delete_confirmation_modal').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>

<p id="1">This is a item to delete.</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

<!-- Delete Modal content-->

<div class="modal fade" id="delete_confirmation_modal" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
 <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 260.5px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Do you really want to delete this Category?</h4>
   </div>
   <form role="form" method="post" action="category_delete" id="delete_data">
    <input type="hidden" id="delete_item_id" name="id" value="12">
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

You should change the form action according to your requirement.

Happy coading :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try more reusable my solution with **callback** function. In this function you can use POST request or some logic.
Used libraries: **JQuery 3>** and **Bootstrap 3>**.

https://jsfiddle.net/axnikitenko/gazbyv8v/

**Html code for test:**

```
...
<body>
    <a href='#' id="remove-btn-a-id" class="btn btn-default">Test Remove Action</a>
</body>
...
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    function remove() {
        alert('Remove Action Start!');
    }
    // Example of initializing component data
    this.cmpModalRemove = new ModalConfirmationComponent('remove-data', remove,
        'remove-btn-a-id', {
            txtModalHeader: 'Header Text For Remove', txtModalBody: 'Body For Text Remove',
            txtBtnConfirm: 'Confirm', txtBtnCancel: 'Cancel'
        });
    this.cmpModalRemove.initialize();
});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// COMPONENT SCRIPT
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Script processing data for confirmation dialog.
 * Used libraries: JQuery 3> and Bootstrap 3>.
 *
 * @param name unique component name at page scope
 * @param callback function which processing confirm click
 * @param actionBtnId button for open modal dialog
 * @param text localization data, structure:
 *              > txtModalHeader - text at header of modal dialog
 *              > txtModalBody - text at body of modal dialog
 *              > txtBtnConfirm - text at button for confirm action
 *              > txtBtnCancel - text at button for cancel action
 *
 * @constructor
 * @author Aleksey Nikitenko
 */
function ModalConfirmationComponent(name, callback, actionBtnId, text) {
    this.name = name;
    this.callback = callback;
    // Text data
    this.txtModalHeader =   text.txtModalHeader;
    this.txtModalBody =     text.txtModalBody;
    this.txtBtnConfirm =    text.txtBtnConfirm;
    this.txtBtnCancel =     text.txtBtnCancel;
    // Elements
    this.elmActionBtn = $('#' + actionBtnId);
    this.elmModalDiv = undefined;
    this.elmConfirmBtn = undefined;
}

/**
 * Initialize needed data for current component object.
 * Generate html code and assign actions for needed UI
 * elements.
 */
ModalConfirmationComponent.prototype.initialize = function () {
    // Generate modal html and assign with action button
    $('body').append(this.getHtmlModal());
    this.elmActionBtn.attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    this.elmActionBtn.attr('data-target', '#'+this.getModalDivId());
    // Initialize needed elements
    this.elmModalDiv =  $('#'+this.getModalDivId());
    this.elmConfirmBtn = $('#'+this.getConfirmBtnId());
    // Assign click function for confirm button
    var object = this;
    this.elmConfirmBtn.click(function() {
        object.elmModalDiv.modal('toggle'); // hide modal
        object.callback(); // run callback function
    });
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// HTML GENERATORS
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Methods needed for get html code of modal div.
 *
 * @returns {string} html code
 */
ModalConfirmationComponent.prototype.getHtmlModal = function () {
    var result = '<div class="modal fade" id="' + this.getModalDivId() + '"';
    result +=' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';
    result += '<div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">';
    result += this.txtModalHeader + '</div><div class="modal-body">' + this.txtModalBody + '</div>';
    result += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    result += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">';
    result += this.txtBtnCancel + '</button>';
    result += '<button id="'+this.getConfirmBtnId()+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">';
    result += this.txtBtnConfirm + '</button>';
    return result+'</div></div></div></div>';
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// UTILITY
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Get id element with name prefix for this component.
 *
 * @returns {string} element id
 */
ModalConfirmationComponent.prototype.getModalDivId = function () {
    return this.name + '-modal-id';
};

/**
 * Get id element with name prefix for this component.
 *
 * @returns {string} element id
 */
ModalConfirmationComponent.prototype.getConfirmBtnId = function () {
    return this.name + '-confirm-btn-id';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### POST Recipe with navigation to target page and reusable Blade file

dfsq's answer is very nice. I modified it a bit to fit my needs: I actually needed a modal for the case that, after clicking, the user would also be navigated to the corresponding page. Executing the query asynchronously is not always what one needs.

Using `Blade` I created the file `resources/views/includes/confirmation_modal.blade.php`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmation-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>{{ $headerText }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ $bodyText }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <form action="" method="POST" style="display:inline">
                    {{ method_field($verb) }}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" value="{{ $confirmButtonText }}" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#confirmation-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        href = $(e.relatedTarget).data('href');

        // change href of button to corresponding target
        $(this).find('form').attr('action', href);
    });
</script>
```

Now, using it is straight-forward:

```
<a data-href="{{ route('data.destroy', ['id' => $data->id]) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmation-modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a>
```

Not much changed here and the modal can be included like this:

```
@include('includes.confirmation_modal', ['headerText' => 'Delete Data?', 'bodyText' => 'Do you really want to delete these data? This operation is irreversible.',
'confirmButtonText' => 'Remove Data', 'verb' => 'DELETE'])
```

Just by putting the verb in there, it uses it. This way, CSRF is also utilized.

Helped me, maybe it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is my confirm box "jquery component" for bootstrap
Just use this in your code:

```
function ConfirmBox({title,message,result}){
 let confirm = $(`
            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="confirmBox" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabelSmall" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="text-align:center">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabelSmall">${title}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            ${message}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirmButton">sure</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
 `);

  //append confirm box to the DOM
  $("body").append(confirm);
  confirm.modal();
 //handlers
        confirm.find("button.confirmButton").one("click",function(){
            result(true);
            confirm.modal("hide");
        });

        confirm.find("button.close").one("click",function(){
            result(false);
            confirm.modal("hide");
        })
        //remove modal after hiding it
        confirm.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            confirm.remove();
        });
}
```