# Confirm deletion using Bootstrap 3 modal box

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, confirm

I need to confirm deletion using Bootstrap 3 modal box (YES/NO). How can I create this?

HTML code:

```
<form action="blah" method="POST">
    <button class='btn' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete">
        <span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42346781/4316802

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need the modal in your HTML. When the delete button is clicked it popup the modal. It's also important to prevent the click of that button from submitting the form. When the confirmation is clicked the form will submit.

```js
   

 $('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function(e) {
      var $form = $(this).closest('form');
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#confirm').modal({
          backdrop: 'static',
          keyboard: false
      })
      .on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
          $form.trigger('submit');
        });
      $("#cancel").on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#confirm').modal.model('hide');
      });
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
</form>

<div id="confirm" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, with one side note: If I click in delete, after If I click in cancel, then I click in delete again, in my case scenario, the submit is sent 2 times. It should submit only one.

Comment: @Khrys, you should verify that you have included `e.prevenDefault()`

Comment: There's a problem here. Take notice that if you are using this to confirm delete something with some kind of ID. What happens is, if you click "Cancel" the event will still be attached to the modal. If you after click another thing to delete, it will delete both.

Comment: for the issue on the previous comments Pedro noted. $('#confirm').unbind() helps to unbind attached events

Comment: Check my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/37307703#37307703 for a reusable component.

Comment: @NigelAngel  If I no of times click on `Cancel` button. Then the `.one('click', '#delete', function(e) {})` call no of times. If i click first 3 times cancel button then click on `Delete` button my `.one({})` executes 4 times. Please check.

Comment: //clear all existing events of modal dialog as shown below before opening it in order to prevent delete called multiple times
       $('#confirm').off();

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`Bootbox`](http://bootboxjs.com/) dialog boxes

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btnDelete').click(function() {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure want to delete?", function(result) {
      alert("Confirm result: " + result);
    });
  });
});
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7oyn4wgRPbMOILDEY1W1?p=preview)

Comment: Be careful, bootbox may conflict with bootstrap modals. Sorry for responding to old question but I just came across with this problem.

Answer (score 12):

I've the same problem just today. This is my solution (which I think is better and simpler):

```
<!-- Modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="frmPrenotazione" tabindex="-1">
    <!-- CUTTED -->
    <div id="step1" class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase btn btn-default" id="btnDelete"> Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal confirm -->
<div class="modal" id="confirmModal" style="display: none; z-index: 1050;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="confirmMessage">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmCancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my .js:

```
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function(e){
    confirmDialog(YOUR_MESSAGE_STRING_CONST, function(){
        //My code to delete
    });
});

function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
    var fClose = function(){
        modal.modal("hide");
    };
    var modal = $("#confirmModal");
    modal.modal("show");
    $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
    $("#confirmOk").unbind().one('click', onConfirm).one('click', fClose);
    $("#confirmCancel").unbind().one("click", fClose);
}
```

Using `unbind` before the `one` prevents that the removal function is invoked at the next opening of the dialog.

I hope this could be helpful.

Follow a complete example:

```js
var YOUR_MESSAGE_STRING_CONST = "Your confirm message?";
      $('#btnDelete').on('click', function(e){
      confirmDialog(YOUR_MESSAGE_STRING_CONST, function(){
       //My code to delete
          console.log("deleted!");
      });
     });

        function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
         var fClose = function(){
         modal.modal("hide");
         };
         var modal = $("#confirmModal");
         modal.modal("show");
         $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
         $("#confirmOk").unbind().one('click', onConfirm).one('click', fClose);
         $("#confirmCancel").unbind().one("click", fClose);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Modal dialog -->
<div id="frmTest" tabindex="-1">
    <!-- CUTTED -->
      <div id="step1" class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase btn btn-default" id="btnDelete"> Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Modal confirm -->
<div class="modal" id="confirmModal" style="display: none; z-index: 1050;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body" id="confirmMessage">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmCancel">Cancel</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

simple way to use modals is with [eModal](http://saribe.github.io/eModal)!

Ex from [github](http://saribe.github.io/eModal/#confirm):

1. Link to eModal.js `<script src="//rawgit.com/saribe/eModal/master/dist/eModal.min.js"></script>`

```js
    var options = {
            message: "The famouse question?",
            title: 'Header title',
            size: 'sm',
            callback: function(result) { result ? doActionTrue(result) :    doActionFalse(); },
            subtitle: 'smaller text header',
            label: "True"   // use the possitive lable as key
            //...
        };
                     
    eModal.confirm(options);
```

```html
 <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/saribe/eModal/master/dist/eModal.min.js"></script>
```

**Tip: You can use change the default label name! { label: 'Yes' | 'True'| 'OK' }**

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm')
        .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
            //delete function
        });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a49cA/1/)

For your button:

```
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs launchConfirm' type="button" name="remove_levels"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button></td>
```

Comment: This isn't within the context of the given code. How does OP apply this to his/her code?

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1):

Create modal dialog in HTML with id="confirmation" and use function showConfirmation.

Also remember you should to unbind (modal.unbind()) cancel and success buttons after hide modal dialog. If you do not make this you will get double binding.
For example: if you open dialog once and press 'Cancel' and then open dialog in second time and press 'Ok' you will get 2 executions of success callback.

```
showConfirmation = function(title, message, success, cancel) {
    title = title ? title : 'Are you sure?';
    var modal = $("#confirmation");
    modal.find(".modal-title").html(title).end()
        .find(".modal-body").html(message).end()
        .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            modal.unbind();
        });
    if (success) {
        modal.one('click', '.modal-footer .btn-primary', success);
    }
    if (cancel) {
        modal.one('click', '.modal-header .close, .modal-footer .btn-default', cancel);
    }
};

// bind confirmation dialog on delete buttons
$(document).on("click", ".delete-event, .delete-all-event", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var success = function(){
        alert('window.location.href=url');
    }
    var cancel = function(){
        alert('Cancel');
    };
    if (self.data('confirmation')) {
        var title = self.data('confirmation-title') ? self.data('confirmation-title') : undefined;
        var message = self.data('confirmation');
        showConfirmation(title, message, success, cancel);
    } else {
        success();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yiiBoy/hne9sp6g/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
  .on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
    $form.trigger('submit');
  });
  $("#cancel").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm').modal.model('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="POST">
  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
</form>
<div id="confirm" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is not working as below changes needed:

1. Need to define id="cancel" on cancel button

   ```
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn">Cancel</button>
   ```
2. cancel click event changes as below

   ```
    $('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function(e) {
      var $form = $(this).closest('form');
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#confirm').modal({
          backdrop: 'static',
          keyboard: false
      })
      .on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
          $form.trigger('submit');
        })
      .on('click','#cancel', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#confirm').modal.model('hide');
      });
    });
   ```