# how to use bootstrap confirm box inside anchor code of codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I don't know how to embed bootstrap confirm delete code inside anchor code of CodeIgniter.

```
foreach($books as $row)
{
    //Add each result row into table
    $this->table->add_row(
        $row['fname'],
        $row['email'],
        $row['pass'],
        $row['image'],
        anchor('welcome/remove_rcrd/'.$row['id'], 'delete'),
        anchor('welcome/edit/'.$row['id'], 'Edit'));
}
```

I want to add bootstrap confirmation box when I click delete anchor or link

Comment: I think this will help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636819/confirm-delete-using-bootstrap-3-modal-box]

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

```
<?php $onclick = array('onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure?')");?>
<?=anchor("welcome/delete/$row->id","Delete", $onclick);?>
```

Comment: can u elaborate more as i want to use bootstrap alert box

Comment: i think this link may help you http://heera.it/bootstrap-3-delete-confirm-dialog#.VMy0ASuUdPA