# How to make a modal window with options as js confirm?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make a modal window with options as js confirm?

For example, I have this: `<a href="/calc-delete.php?" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to remove?')">Delete</a>`

How to do something like the my example, but with modal window? It would be cool, if it would be a bootstrap modal window and that the answer would show in the same modal window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confirm delete using bootstrap 3 modal box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636819/confirm-delete-using-bootstrap-3-modal-box)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

**HTML**

```
<form action ="#" method="POST">
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
</form>

<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function(e){
        var $form=$(this).closest('form');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
            .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
                $form.trigger('submit');
            });
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dave17/L3ddq/871/)**

For multiple **Button**(multiple link on same model)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dave17/L3ddq/873)**

Comment: if I click on delete in the modal window, where's he headed? how to write your way?

Comment: @TriSTaR : in form action(**<form action ="#" method="POST">**).

Comment: Thank you) Works great... One question is how to do that: clicking on the delete button in a separate file displays: data successfully removed.. as it is on the same modal window to show?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**The "Trigger" part:**

To trigger the modal window, you need to use a button or a link.

Then include the two data-* attributes:

`data-toggle="modal"` opens the modal window
`data-target="#myModal"` points to the id of the modal

**The "Modal" part:**

The parent `<div>` of the modal must have an ID that is the same as the value of the data-target attribute used to trigger the modal ("myModal").

The .modal class identifies the content of `<div>` as a modal and brings focus to it.

The `.fade` class adds a transition effect which fades the modal in and out. Remove this class if you do not want this effect.

The attribute `role="dialog"` improves accessibility for people using screen readers.

The `.modal-dialog` class sets the proper width and margin of the modal.

**The "Modal content" part:**

The `<div>` with `class="modal-content"` styles the modal (border, background-color, etc.). Inside this `<div>`, add the modal's header, body, and footer.

The .modal-header class is used to define the style for the header of the modal. The `<button>` inside the header has a `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute which closes the modal if you click on it. The .close class styles the close button, and the `.modal-title` class styles the header with a proper line-height.

The `.modal-body` class is used to define the style for the body of the modal. Add any HTML markup here; paragraphs, images, videos, etc.

The `.modal-footer` class is used to define the style for the footer of the modal. Note that this area is right aligned by default.

Answer (score 0):

w3c Schools have a very nice article on how to create a modal

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

All you have to do, is open the modal with your `onclick=return openModal()` and handle the php call from your **OK** button in your modal.