# Confirm with modal bootstrap won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and want to use modal launch with a button for confirms the user deletion action. But the example code from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples) seems won't work with me. So I was looking some examples from forums and still won't work. One of example that I tried was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap). It's been 2 hours and I still don't know whats wrong with my code. The confirms button won't work so whenever I clicked the confirm button, it's do nothing. When I moved my mouse cursor over btn-ok, I didn't see the link overview in the browser.

Here my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-href="delete.php?id=54" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Delete</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wboxfvse Also, Bootstrap was an incorrect tag. Please look at tag descriptions when including them.

Comment: Did you include the JS script from Bootstrap?

Comment: What does "link overview" mean?

Comment: @isherwood, yes the modul is show but when I confirmed the delete, its do nothing. Link overview is an link info when your cursor is over on a link and the browser will show you the link in the left-bot side browser.

Comment: @Drown yes, sir i did but still won't work

Comment: @BandiSu What results do you expect from this modal? It opens fine and of course nothing happens when you click on delete, cause there's no `href` for your `a` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gildonei/pho9zp2f/9/

**Html Code**

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-delete" href="delete.php?id=54">Delete</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">...</div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="bt-modal-cancel" href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a> 
                <a id="bt-modal-confirm" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(function(){
    var $myModal = jQuery('#my-modal');

    // Modal to delete record
    var $btDelete = jQuery('.btn-delete');
    if ($btDelete.length) {
        $btDelete.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            var id = url.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

            // Objects from alert modal
            var $dsBody = $myModal.find('div.modal-body');
            var $dsTitle = $myModal.find('div.modal-header h3');
            var $btConfirm = jQuery('#bt-modal-confirm');
            var $btCancel = jQuery('#bt-modal-cancel');

            $dsBody.html('<p>Are you sure you want to delete the record #' + id + '?</p>');
            $dsTitle.html('Delete Record');

            $myModal.modal({
                show: true
            });


            $btConfirm.attr('href', url).removeAttr('data-dismiss');
            $btCancel.click(function(){
                $dsTitle.html('Warning');
                $dsBody.html('<p>Notice</p>');
                $btConfirm.attr('href', '#').attr('data-dismiss', 'modal');
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: This code is working for me, sir, thank you very much, I appreciate your help. But I still don't understand whats wrong with my code so it should use this js.

Comment: Your code didn't work becouse your Delete Confirmation button doesn't have an action. Note your confirm delete doe's not have a href attribute. In my code, i passed the href from link to button in modal

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is a little unclear. If you're trying to hide the modal and perform the delete when the user clicks delete, then you should try binding to the click event of the delete button:

```
$('.btn-ok').click(function() {
   /* Add any code here to delete the user */
   $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

[Here is a another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh7ojpr1/) (copied from @isherwood's comment with edits)

Comment: The problem is my button won't run the link in that defined in data-href="delete.php?id=54" when I clicked btn-ok