# bootstrap confirm box alert not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert, confirm

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<script>
function confirm() {
BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');}
</script>

<input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="confirm()" />
```

Hi. I'm trying to make a bootstrap confirm alert which is activated by a button input. I'm a total beginner, so it's probably something fundamental/obvious that I'm missing... Any help very much appreciated. Mike.

Comment: The scripts tags are incorrect, there needs to be one opening script tag, with a source, followed by a closing script tag, for each URL.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Also, isn't BootstrapDialog a plugin ?

Comment: good spot - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few things:

- your `script` tag is incorrect, need to be fixed
- you most likely need the `bootstrap.css`
- you need to add `bootstrap-dialog.js`

```js
 function confirm() {
   BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.1/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="confirm()" />
```