# give user options when clicking on bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, echo

```
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=$result[exportid]\"><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></button></a>";
```

The button above loads delete.php

When the user clicks on the button i want to display a yes/no window. If the user clicks yes, it needs to load the delete.php(with id info). When click no it needs to load an other php file.

what is a good way to do this? i have tried using  JavaScript but can't get it to work.

Comment: Check the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap, older version of bs, but still valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirm delete modal/dialog with Twitter bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

1st no need to add a button inside a link, just style the link:

```
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=$result[exportid]\" class='btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delete-button'></a>";
```

Then attach to the buttons click event in javascript (jquery) and show a confirmation:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.delete-button').click(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var deleteUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        var otherUrl = 'some other url';
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item')){
             window.location = deleteUrl;
        }else{
             window.location = otherUrl;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make your confirm dialog like following:

```
<!-- Modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myForm" tabindex="-1">
    <!-- CUTTED -->
    <div id="step1" class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase btn btn-default" id="btnDelete"> Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal confirm -->
<div class="modal" id="confirmModal" style="display: none; z-index: 1050;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="confirmMessage">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmCancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

File .js:

```
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function(e){
    confirmDialog(YOUR_MESSAGE_STRING_CONST, function(){
        //My code to delete
    });
});

function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
    var fClose = function(){
        modal.modal("hide");
    };
    var modal = $("#confirmModal");
    modal.modal("show");
    $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
    $("#confirmOk").one('click', onConfirm);
    $("#confirmOk").one('click', fClose);
    $("#confirmCancel").one("click", fClose);
}
```

Using `one` instead of `on` prevents that the removal function is invoked at the next opening of the dialog.

I hope this could be helpful.

Follow a complete text example:

```js
var YOUR_MESSAGE_STRING_CONST = "Your confirm message?";
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function(e){
  confirmDialog(YOUR_MESSAGE_STRING_CONST, function(){
    //My code on OK click
  });
});

function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
  var fClose = function(){
  modal.modal("hide");
  };
  var modal = $("#confirmModal");
  modal.modal("show");
  $("#confirmMessage").empty().append(message);
  $("#confirmOk").one('click', onConfirm);
  $("#confirmOk").one('click', fClose);
  $("#confirmCancel").one("click", fClose);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Modal dialog -->
<div id="frmTest" tabindex="-1">
  <!-- CUTTED -->
    <div id="step1" class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase btn btn-default" id="btnDelete"> Delete</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal confirm -->
<div class="modal" id="confirmModal" style="display: none; z-index: 1050;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body" id="confirmMessage">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmCancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Bootstrap Modal component](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/). It does exactly what you need it to do.