# Displaying Bootstrap confirmation message box in ASP.net MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, view, confirmation

In my project, page table is generating by database content. each row consistes with button called Approve. when I click the button id related row is updated,

My controller as follows,

```
   public ActionResult approveLoanByID(int id)
    {
        var logic = new LoanDetailsDataLogic();
        bool result = logic.approveLoan(id);
        return RedirectToAction("UnsuccessLoan");
    }
```

I need to add boostrap confirmation model/box when click the approve button. How can I do this using MVC. My view as follows

Part of my view code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOAN_STATUS_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOAN_STATUS_DES)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("approveLoanByID", "LoanDetails",new { id = item.ID } )'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Approve" />
        </td>
        <td>

            @*@Html.ActionLink("Checkout and view order list", "rejectLoanByID" , "LoanDetails" , new { id=item.ID }, new { onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to click this link?')" })*@ 

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I tried somthing like this, but I need to use boostrap model to confirm approve.

sample boostrap model

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteLabel">Deleting a Notification</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You have selected to delete this notification.</p>
                <p>
                    If this was the action that you wanted to do,
                    please confirm your choice, or cancel and return
                    to the page.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteConfirm">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You method is changing data, so it should be a POST, not a GET.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok sir, can you give me sample code to solve this? please how can I do this

Comment: Refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir I'm new to asp. I dont have idea to solve this. I read that Q&A but I dont know how to use it for my project,please help