# How do I add a confirm message to a logout prompt in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I have attempted to use the following code to add a confirmation message to a logout option in a dropdown menu, but it's not working.

`<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "dropdown-item" %>`

I feel like I either made a random misspelling or I'm missing something glaringly obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add in the question the generated HTML of the `link_to`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confirm deletion in modal / dialog using Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-deletion-in-modal-dialog-using-twitter-bootstrap)